# Run typescript on a subdirectory

Tags: typescript, tsc

I have a solidjs project I am working on, and solidjs creates it's own typescript config file in the root directory for managing things in the `src` directory.

I added a `server` directory to the project with an `app.ts` in the root of it and a `tsconfig.json` in that directory to handle type script things in that directory differently than how solidjs is handling things.

From the root directory, if I run
`npx tsc server`

I get the error

```
error TS6231: Could not resolve the path 'server' with the extensions: '.ts', '.tsx', '.d.ts', '.cts', '.d.cts', '.mts', '.d.mts'.
```

but if I cd into that directory and run `npx tsc` everything works fine.

How can I run tsc on that directory without actually cd'ing into that directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify the path to the project that tsc should use. In this case your command should be:

```bash
npx tsc --p ./server
```